# java eclipse-plugin : menuitems appear in windows but not on linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse-plugin, menu

I am extending the tools menu with my own action cmds using the below line in the plugin.xml

```
   ...
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=edit">
         <menu
               id="geditorToolsMenu"
               label="T&amp;ools"
               mnemonic="Tools">
            <dynamic
                  class="com.myproject.eclipse.geditor.editors.ExternalToolsMenuCompoundContributionItem"
                  id="my.project.MyCompoundContributionItem">
            </dynamic>
            <visibleWhen>
               <with
                     variable="activePart">
                  <or>
                     <or>
                        <instanceof
                              value="org.eclipse.ui.views.navigator.IResourceNavigator">
                        </instanceof>
                        <instanceof
                              value="com.myproject.eclipse.geditor.editors.GBaseEditor">
                        </instanceof>
                        <instanceof
                              value="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart">
                        </instanceof>
                        <instanceof
                              value="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.ProjectExplorer">
                        </instanceof>
                     </or>
                  </or>
               </with>
            </visibleWhen>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
   ...
```

The problem I am facing is that the "Tools" menu appears fine with all the menuitems in windows but on linux the "Tools" menu appears but on clicking it, I see a tiny bubble like popup.

Any ideas what might be causing this ?

Comment: What eclipse are you using ? 3.3 ? 3.4 ? 3.4.2 ?

Comment: I am using 3.4.2. 
Do you see something there?

Answer (score 1):

The only problems of "menu display" for Linux in eclipse 3.4.x are described in [this **bug 227243**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=227243).

Can you check if the scenarios detailed in the comments in that bug apply to your case ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing with a completely new and clean install of Eclipse?  My experience with Eclipse so far shows that over time, Eclipse can sometimes get a little messed up or confused and needs to be reinstalled fresh in order to work right sometimes.  I shouldn't blame Eclipse, though, because it could totally be operator error.